# Show outcome of addition

Tags: luatex, tex-core, loops, e-tex, variable

I am using a for-loop which initiates variable \n. How do I print the result of (\n+2)? I have read of e-Tex and LuaTex, but this all seems overkill for this simple operation?

Thanks already!

Comment: answers up to now assume either etex or luatex, and the op wonders whether this is an overkill. Can it be done in core TeX?

Comment: @erreka with counters it can. But probably that's not the input type and the OP uses a modern (e-TeX-supporting engine) anyway.

Comment: If any of the answers solved your problem please consider accepting one of those.

Answer (score 8):

A very simple version: Using `\the\numexpr`.

[image: addition]

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\n{1}
\begin{document}
    \n\ + 2: \the\numexpr\n+2
\end{document}
```

---

Update: The more comprehensive version. The command `\allmightymath` will evaluate integer expressions (even if they are not simplified) using `expl3`.

[image: integer expressions]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{expl3,xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand { \allmightymath } { m }
    {
        \int_eval:n { #1 }
    }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\def\n{1}
\begin{document}
    \n\ + 2: \the\numexpr\n+2\\
    \allmightymath{4*(\n-1)+2}\\
    \def\n{2}
    \allmightymath{4*(\n-1)+2}
\end{document}
```

Comment: n is an integer, and this worked perfectly. Thanks! :-)

Comment: Now it turns out I need to evaluate 4(n-1)+2. I tried \the\numexpr4{n-1)+2, but this doesn't work. Do I use pgfmath instead?

Comment: Try `\n*4-2` instead.

Comment: Of course `\numexpr` *does* use e-TeX, which is incorporated into the default PdfTeX engine, used by the `pdflatex` and even the `latex` binary (which simply calls pdftex in DVI mode). LaTeX *requires* e-TeX since sometime in 2016. (To see this: put `\def\n{1} \n\ + 2: \the\numexpr\n+2 \bye` into a `.tex` file and run `tex` on it; you'll get “Undefined control sequence” for `\numexpr`.)

Answer (score 5):

Here's an example of the very powerful [PGF](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf) package. With it you can do some awesome math inside your TeX document.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfmath,pgffor}
\begin{document}

\foreach \n in {0,1,...,100}{
  \pgfmathparse{int(\n+2)}
  \pgfmathresult\par
}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a LuaLaTeX-based solution. It initiates a `for`-loop and prints out, for each `n` from `1` to `20`, the values of `n`, `n-2`, and `4(n-1)+2`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\directlua{%
   for n = 1 , 20 do
     tex.sprint ( n .. " ".. n+2 .. " ".. 4*(n-1)+2 .. "\string\\par" )
   end}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `xfp`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xfp}
\begin{document}
$1 + 2 = \fpeval{1+2}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xfp}
\begin{document}
\def\n{1}
$4 (n-1) + 2 = \fpeval{4*(\n-1)+2}$
\end{document}
```

[image]